# using setenv in makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to use setenv variable in my makefile but when I execute my make file it gives setenv: command not found.

How can I use it?

Actually I wanted to run a shell script which sets multiple environment variables.

Since the list is very huge I dont have an option except to use the scripts. I cant set them manually like 
abcd:= /xx/yy/zz

Please suggest.

P.S. the same command 
setenv xxx yyy works very well in shell
it just fails when I use in makefile directly or makefile with a script having this command.
'

Answer (score 4):

Why do not you use export command ?

Comment: actually I have pre-written scripts which I used to run on shell now I want to move it to make file. There are lot of places where I used this command and manually convering all to export will kill lots of my time.

Comment: "manually converting" ? why not use a perl one-liner to replace them all ?

Answer (score 3):

Running the script to set the environment variable will not work as the shell run a separate process & will not reflect in your current shell. You will need to `source` the shell script. You can use `source` or `.` based on your shell.  Following is a sample for your reference where setvar.sh sets a variable & print.sh prints it; in the Makefile (mkfile) setvar.sh is being sourced using `.`

```
$ cat setvar.sh 

export TEST=ABC 

$ cat print.sh 

echo $TEST
$ cat mkfile
test:
    . ./setvar.sh && ./print.sh

.SILENT:test
$ make -f mkfile
ABC
```

You can also `include` I guess for example,

```
$ cat mkfile2 
include setvar.sh
test:
    ./print.sh

.SILENT:test
$ make -f mkfile2
ABC
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Look at

- `make -e`
- and [Communicating Variables to a Sub-make](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Variables_002fRecursion.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think setenv is not a builtin to the `sh` shell.  If you are using GNU Make that is the default shell used.  In your situation you probably want to use a different shell, like bash.  You do this by setting the SHELL variable in the makefile to what you want like:

```
SHELL := /usr/bin/bash
```

For more information checkout [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Choosing-the-Shell) section of the GNU Make manual.  It details the different behavior of the SHELL variable and how it is, or isn't inherited from the shell make is invoked from on different platforms.

EDIT: I agree with the implication of the other posters that you are probably not setting enviroment variables the way you think you should be and would not be using the setenv command at. I am just responding to your original question.  To learn about variables in make files checkout [these other sections](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#toc_Using-Variables) in the GNU Make manual.

Answer (score -1):

```
export MY_VAR := "/package/your_path"
```